# Why is an open interval needed in this definition? (definition of a limit of a function)

Tags: limits, definition, intuition

Here's a part of the definition Ross' Elementary Analysis states for [limits of a function](https://books.google.com/books?id=7b8_AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA153):

> **20.3 Definition**
> (a) For $a\in\mathbb R$ and a function $f$ we write $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=L$ provided $\lim_{x\to a^S} f(x)=L$ for some set $S=J\setminus\{a\}$ where $J$ is an open interval containing $a$.
> $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ is called the *[two-sided] limit of $f$ at $a$.* Note $f$ need not be defined at $a$ and, even if $f$ is defined at $a$, the value $f(a)$ need not equal $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$. In fact, $f(a)=\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ if and only if $f$ is defined at $a$ and $f$ is continuous at $a$.
> (b) For $a\in\mathbb R$ and a function $f$ we write $\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x)=L$ provided  $\lim_{x\to a^S} f(x)=L$ for some open interval $S=(a,b)$.
> $\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x)$ is the *right-hand limit of $f$ at $a$.* Again $f$ need not be defined at $a$.

In both parts of the definition, why are open intervals needed? Would it fail if it were a closed interval instead?

Comment: Technically, you don't need an open interval for the definition to work, but it is the "easiest" way to make sure that if the limit exists, it is unique. There are less limiting conditions one could apply, but they complicate the definition, and this is "good enough" to start with.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How would having a closed interval make it "harder"?

Comment: Closed intervals can be a problem in the first case if $a$ is not in the interior of $S$. So the closed interval $[a,b]$ is an interval that contains $a$, but it isn't a two-sided limit. Open interval thus requires values on both sides of $a$. For any other closed intervals, the associated open interval is just as good.

Comment: Notice that by the time you get to this point in the text, you have already defined the notation $\lim_{x\to a^S} f(x),$ which is evidently a more general definition of the limit of a function. I don't know what restrictions the earlier definition places on $S$, but it's certainly possible to make a good definition in which $S$ is not required to be an open interval or a punctured open interval. The definition here appears to be designed so that the notation $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ will refer to a two-sided limit similar to the way it is used in many other calculus textbooks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my opinions (Not accepted facts from math society):
Definitions usually should be short and provide good intuitive for incoming definitions.

1. Open intervals guaranty that some points in two side of point $a$ exist. But if $J=[a,c]$ or $J=[d,a]$ then $\lim_{x\to a^S}f(x)$ will be one sided. So it needs to use some extra words explaining that $a$ shouldn't be at start or end of which isn't short any more.
2. Open intervals will have good relevance to their generalized things in topology (open set) which needs for definition of continuous functions.

Answer (score 0):

An open interval is not needed and is stronger than necessary.

Usually, in other books, this definition will only require that $a$ be a [limit point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulation_point).†

I think perhaps for simplicity, Ross's *Elementary Analysis* tries to avoid having to talk about limit points. So, it uses the stronger condition that $a$ is in an open interval (where $f$ is defined on this interval except possibly at $a$). It can be shown that this condition implies that $a$ is a limit point of the domain of $f$.

---

A closed interval would fail. I consider only part (a) of the definition:

Define $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by $f(x)=-1$ for $x<0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\ge 0$. Let $a=0$.

Intuitively, we "want" $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ to be undefined.

But now if we allow $J$ to be the closed interval $[a,1]=[0,1]$, so that $S=J\setminus \{a\}=(0,1]$, by the definition, we'd have $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=1$, which isn't what we "want".

---

†As for why this is required, see e.g. [Limit of function at non limit point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4512385/limit-of-function-at-non-limit-point).